# Mysql, сортировка по двум полям

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с полями `id, parent_id`. Как ее отсортировать таким образом, что бы после каждой записи шли те, в которых есть `parent_id` соответствующий этой записи

```
id   parent_id
1    null
2    null
3    4
4    null
5    1
6    null
```

после сортировки:

```
 id   parent_id
    1    null
    5    1
    2    null
    4    null
    3    4
    6    null
```

Comment: сколько может быть уровней parent-child?

Comment: @Igor Неограниченное количество

Comment: если есть записи `7 5` и `8 1` - какая должна идти после `5 1`?

Answer (score 3):

вот это попробуйте

```
SELECT id, parent_id
  FROM tt
 ORDER BY coalesce(parent_id,id), coalesce(parent_id,0)
```